# iPhone Contact App's "Contact View/Edit View" XCODE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm actually making an app in which there is a table view (listing all the courses)
Clicking on one of it will show the details of that course. (detail view)
Now what I want to make is, the Edit Mode of that detail view..
and i want to give it a feel like iphone's native app :P

when i look into contact's app, when i click "Edit" in a contact, it doesn't seems to change the WHOLE view controller, but just hide/show the old/new fields and buttons..

if its not a new view controller (for the edit), then how is it working exactly?
if its a new view controller, then i guess, its pretty simple, pushing the view controller into the navigation stack..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view controller's "-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated" method, override the current behaviour:

```
 - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates]; // Tell the table to begin updates to ensure that the following reloads and animations all happen at once

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    // set the table editing if you are not using UITableViewController

    // reload any rows that may need updating for the new state

    if (editing) {
        // tell the table view to insert the editing rows
    } else {
        // tell the table view to remove the editing rows
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates]; // commit the updates.
}
```

So now, as the view controller (and the table view) enters editing mode, the view controller tells to table to insert rows at the editing spot. The table itself also moves into editing mode.

As the view controller moves out of editing (and the table view with it) the rows that were editing specific are removed.

Note that if you're not using a UITableViewController subclass, but just a subclass of UIViewController itself, you need to tell the table view to move into editing at the same time:

```
[tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
```

If you need to reload, or insert rows, etc, the delegate and datasource methods need to check if the table is in editing mode, and return the rows required for either the editing or non-editing mode.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView.editing) {
        return /*editing count*/;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView.editing) {
        // return cells for the editing state.
    }

    // return cells based on the standard state.
}
```

Comment: okay i get this thing..but how does the CELL LABEL change into a TEXTFIELD?

Comment: They would also reload the cell at that location. Read my alterations to the above code to get an idea how they all happen together.

Comment: Okay beginUpdate and endUpdate fixed the problem.. P.s i used custom cell view to show a textfield instead of a label and set their 'enabled' property on setEditing function..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are write native contact's app in iPhone does not change the WHOLE view controller, but just hide/show the old/new fields and buttons..

For that purpose first you have to take a UITableView then you can add your views either by taking different sections and then rows in that section or use UITableView's header view to 
show some views like contact's app in contact's app Contact's ImageView and Contact name and company fields are displayed in UITableView's header view.

You can also use UITableView's footer view to add buttons or some of your views at bottom of table view.

Like this you can show the detail view for course which is selected by user.

For edit mode, when user taps on Edit button you need to reload your table view and provide appropriate views to table view in table view's delegate method, for this purpose you need to keep track of mode i.e course detail view mode or course edit mode.

OR

You can use Two separate tables altogether for two different mode.

When user taps on specific course load next view displaying course details,

when user taps on Edit button remove course details table form view e.g [tableview removeFromSuperView];

and add Course edit table having different view on it,

e.g [self.view addSubview:courseEditTable];